# How to display other inputs in main input with original value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have an issue with trying to figure out how to get this to work. I want to make a dropdown selection, and I want all the selections in the dropdown to show up in the main input box along with the original input value.

Here is my form that I am using to send the values to ajax to send to my php file.

```
<div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
    <input type="text" name="input1" class="form-control" id="filter" id="searchbox" placeholder="Something..."/ required>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <h4 class="text-center">Advanced Search</h4>
                            <label for="filter">Option</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="place" id="myList">
                                <option selected></option>
                                <option value="option1">Option1</option>
                                <option value="option2">Option2</option>
                                <option value="option3">Option3</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contain">Location</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="something1" type="text" id="list2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contain">Something2</label>
                                <input class="form-control" name="contain" type="text" id="list3">
                            </div>
                            <p><br/>
                            <button type="submit" id="insideButton" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Advanced Search</button>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="buttonClass" name="submit2" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now I'm trying to get the values from the select dropdown(#myList) and the other inputs(#list2, #list3) and display them in the main input(#filter) along with the value that was entered in (#filter). My code below will display them per keypress but it repeats it since its in the function. How do I get each input to display in the #filter input.

```
$('#list2').on("input", function(){
    var filter = $(this).val();
    var myList = $('#filter').val();
    $('#filter').val(filter + " " + myList);
});
```

Here is a picture of what I would like to accomplish. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Here is a picture of what I would like to accomplish.]

Comment: do you want the value of select box in jquery

Comment: Your markup is strange, you have elements with more than one ID attribute, labels with `for` attributes nowhere near the related input etc?

Comment: change your jquery function to on "change". https://fiddle.jshell.net/rqd9phaf/

Comment: Perfect, yes changing "input" to "change" is exactly what I needed. Thanks Tommy.

Comment: Yeah, sorry bout that adeneo, I was making some minor changes before posting and didn't proof check everything.

Comment: The only issue I have now, is that if the user changes their selection in the dropdown from option1 to option2, it keeps option1 in the input and adds option2 and continues to add each option continuously. How can I allow it to only add the selected option or input once and then change it to another choice if selected.

Answer (score 0):

hello  If I am understanding correctly according to your image and your piece of code  that you want to get the all option input value into the main search box if that so you can try this Jquery code

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#insideButton").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#filter").val($("#list3").val()+" "+ $("#list2").val()+" 
          "+$("#myList").val()+" "+$("#filter").val());
          });
          });
</script>
```

I just used one button as submit option you can change it as your wish
you can also write the same code if you want form submit option then there will be a slightly change

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".form-horizontal").on('submit',function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#filter").val($("#list3").val()+" "+ $("#list2").val()+" 
          "+$("#myList").val()+" "+$("#filter").val());
          });
          });
 </script>
```

hope it helps  you can also check this fiddle 
 [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/0ndLLxax/)

Comment: Something similar to that. But if you take a look in the picture I posted of the input box, it has "option4"  "option3"  "OPTION2" "main input", and what I want is, that if the user changes their mind and selects a different option in the dropdown box or types in something different in one of the option input boxes, it will remove the old one from the input and replace it with the new option selected or typed in the input boxes.